# Components in GridBagLayout are put to the center, without taking all free space

Tags: java, swing

I have a GridBagLayout with two components: JRadioButton and JLabel. Text in a label differs by length. This GridbagLayout is added to JPanel. So when I have a lot of components they are not aligned well at the end. Here is what I mean:

```
-----radio btn-label-----
---radio btn-label     --
-------radio btn-lbl-----
```

But I need the following:

```
-radio btn-label        -
-radio btn-label        -
-radio btn-lbl          -
```

This is how my grid looks like for now:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
private JLabel info;
private JRadioButton select;

public MyPanel() {
    this.achiev = achiev;
    achievementInfo = new JLabel();
    selectAchiev = new JRadioButton();

    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    add(selectAchiev, constraints);

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("<html><b>").append("some text").append("</b><p>");
    builder.append("<i>").append("some more text").append("</i>");
    info.setText(builder.toString());
    constraints.gridx = 1;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    add(info, constraints);
}

//--------------

JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BoxLayout(), BoxLayout.YAXIS);
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    panel.add(new MyPanel());
}
```

Comment: [sscce](http://sscce.org)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding 10 panels which all have their own gridbag layout, checkbox and label. So each panel has its own grid, and the width of the cells are computed independantly, based on the components they contain.

If you want a well-aligned single grid, you should have a single panel using GridBagLayout, and add your 10 labels and 10 checkboxes to this unique panel.

Moreover, you should give a weightx > 0 to the label's constraint if you really want it to fill horizontally.

Comment: Oh, `weightx` is what I needed in fact. Thanks.

Comment: That will work only because all your checkboxes have the same size. If they differ in size, you'll need a single grid.

Answer (score 2):

I think you miss the *weightx, weighty* constraints as it is said in this [GrigBadLayout document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html):

> Unless you specify at least one non-zero value for weightx or weighty, all the components clump together in the center of their container. This is because when the weight is 0.0 (the default), the GridBagLayout puts any extra space between its grid of cells and the edges of the container.

If you want to make your components look like that, i refer using [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html)

```
private void init() {
    Box outerBox = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    outerBox.add(createLineWithRadioButtonAndLabel());//line 1
    outerBox.add(createLineWithRadioButtonAndLabel());//line 2
    outerBox.add(createLineWithRadioButtonAndLabel());//line 3

    add(outerBox);
}

private Box createLineWithRadioButtonAndLabel() {
    Box line = new Box(BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
    JRadioButton radio = new JRadioButton("radio button");
    JLabel label = new JLabel("some text");

    line.add(radio);
    line.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(20, 1)));// add some horizontal space. Here is 20
    line.add(label);
    line.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

    return line;
}
```